# Autorun dvd or cd in version 14.04

Tags: dvd, cd, autorun

How do I make a cd or dvd autorun when I insert it? I am using version 14.04. At the moment a folder box with all the individual files opens.

Answer (score 1):

Go System Settings > Details > Removable Media, set an app

[image: Details]

Comment: You beat me to it!  ;)  Gotta learn to type faster here!  =)  +1